# no identifier option in xcode 6 tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am working on UITableView using Xcode 6 but there is no identifier option on xcode when I clicked on tableView as u can see there is no identifier in the attribute inspector.

Comment: Please edit your posting so that it properly includes the image

Answer (score 0):

I feel like now it's called Restoration ID

[image]